# Can I set some sort of "never send error report" on an app that has to be force quit frequently?

Tags: macos, security, error

RSA SecurID. OSX El Capitan.

The app is frequently unresponsive when the computer comes back from sleep. Response from IT Support: "it's not meant to be left running". In other words I'm supposed to quit the app right after I use it. If I don't do that, the app is unresponsive next time I need it. So I have to force quit it.

It seems like there's a whole process involved in Force Quit -- like it's gathering up a stack trace etc. Well in this case there is no point to me reporting the quit it seems; I've reported it a dozen times over the past 9 months and never seen a new version of the app.

Can I permanently elect to not send an error report for a certain application? When I need to use RSA SecurID I need it right then, not 30s later. Waiting just interrupts my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of force quit you could find the name of the process(es) you want to quit using Activity Monitor and then create a script that uses the kill command to get rid of them.

Some details: [Chriswrites](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-view-and-kill-processes-using-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x/)